# How to relate db entries with listview items

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listitem

I'll explain shortly what I am trying to do. I have a custom `listView` which is filled in with the data from `SQLite` database. Once a list item is longclicked, it is added to favourites: I have a separate column in the database, where "1" is assigned for entries added to favourites. Everything is ok by this point.

What I want to do now is to mark favourite list items with stars. I want to make a query to db like `SELECT text (id?) FROM info WHERE favourite = 1` and place a star near the corresponding list item. The problem is I don't know how to call the specific list item  (`checkbox`?) by its `position` (or `text`?) and mark it as selected. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here example of CursorAdapter for list with checkboxes.

```
public class ItemCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int itemNameIndex;
    private int itemCheckIndex;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
public ItemCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, cursor, autoRequery);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ITEM.NAME);
        itemCheckIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ITEM.CHECK);
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
    }
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String name = cursor.getString(itemNameIndex);
        boolean checked = cursor.getInt(itemCheckIndex) > 0;
        TextView nameTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        CheckBox checkChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.item_check);
        checkChk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new onItemCheckChangeListener(name));
        nameTxt.setText(name);
        checkChk.setChecked(checked);
    }
@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        return view;
    }
private class onItemCheckChangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
private String itemName;
public onItemCheckChangeListener(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            dbHelper.changeItemCheck(itemName, isChecked);
        }
}
}
And here example of table inside DBHelper
public static interface ITEM extends BaseColumns {
String TABLE_NAME = "itemTable";
String NAME = "itemName";
String CHECK = "itemCheck";
}
Method to get cursor for list
public Cursor getAllItemCursor() {
return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ITEM.TABLE_NAME, null);
}

and to update checkbox status to db 
public void changeItemCheck(String itemName, boolean isChecked) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ITEM.CHECK, isChecked);
getWritableDatabase().update(ITEM.TABLE_NAME, values, ITEM.NAME + " =? ", new String[] { itemName });
}
```